# Remove white outline on text windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, overlay

So I have a Form and a Label which are totally transparent and only the text should be visible. But whenever I run the program the text looks like this (the black is from my desktop):

[image: this]

What I have done to make the form transparent was setting the FormBorderStyle to None, the Transperency Key to Transparent and the Opacity to 100% for the label I just set it to White which made it transparent.

My goal is to have an overlay of the Desktop to show Information, also if i could make it so that you can click throw the text it would be perfect.

Thanks for any kind of help!

---

## **EDIT:**

Here is the code I am currently using on the Form1_Load event:

```
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Opacity = 100;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Transparent;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        label1.Text = "test" + Environment.NewLine + "test";
```

Comment: May the @Downvoter tell me the reason for it, I kinda want to improve the answer if it seems not good to you.

Comment: OK probably because there is no code to help you with.  But as a huge hint, override the paint event and do it yourself?

Comment: I didn't down vote you.  But, some suggestions.: 1) tag the question with the presentation framework you are using (WinForms, WPF, ...). 2) show the code that you use to set the properties of the form, the labels and whatever else we are looking at.  If you can reduce the code to something with just the barest of repro steps, then people can quickly repro your problem and say "oh, you forgot to remonstrate the carburetor" or whatever the problem might be.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks, I updated the question with new Tags and my code!

Comment: Also @Trey that was actually a pretty good hint, I tried it before but I had the same result, but setting the TextRenderingHint to SingleBitPerPixelGridFit made the difference and fixed the white outline. If you create an answer I would mark it as correct!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  I had a similar project.  Don't worry about the answer bit, I just do this to keep my skills sharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I answer my own question for other people might having the same issue. I ended up using the Paint event on the Form, suggested by Trey. Also from what I found this option does not exist for lables.
This is the code that worked for me:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit; // This makes the diffrence otherwise it does look exactly the same!
g.DrawString("yourText", new Font("Tahoma", 30), Brushes.Black, 100,100);
```